# Exception mapping key type to predicted label

Tags: .net, ml.net

I built a pipeline like this:

```
// PurchaseData.TrainingInputColumnNames is string[] containing the input column names
var predictColumn = nameof(PurchaseData.Brand);
var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(nameof(PurchaseData.CurrentBrand))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding(nameof(PurchaseData.Gender)))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(DefaultColumnNames.Features, PurchaseData.TrainingInputColumnNames))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: DefaultColumnNames.Label, inputColumnName: predictColumn))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Normalize())
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(("PredictedLabel", DefaultColumnNames.Label)))
    .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)


IEstimator<ITransformer> trainer = null;
trainer = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent
    (
    featureColumn: DefaultColumnNames.Features,
    l2Const: 0.0001f, 
    l1Threshold: null,                    
    maxIterations: 200
    );

var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);        

var trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
```

And a prediction class

```
public class PurchaseDataPrediction
{
    public float[] Score;
    public string PredictedLabel;        
}
```

When I try to decode the labels using

```
// https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/test/Microsoft.ML.Tests/Scenarios/Api/Estimators/PredictAndMetadata.cs
VBuffer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> keys = default;
predictionEngine.OutputSchema[nameof(PurchaseDataPrediction.PredictedLabel)].GetKeyValues(ref keys);
```

I get the exception:

> 'Can't bind the IDataView column 'PredictedLabel' of type 'Key' to field or property 'PredictedLabel' of type 'System.String'.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to get the predicted label back (as a string)

```
        // Create Estimator
        var pipe = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Normalize("Features"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "IrisPlantType"), TransformerScope.TrainTest)
            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)
            .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent())
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(("PredictPlant", "PredictedLabel")));

        // Train the pipeline
        var trainedModel = pipe.Fit(trainData);

        // Make predictions
        var predictFunction = trainedModel.CreatePredictionEngine<IrisDataWithStringLabel, IrisPredictionWithStringLabel>(mlContext);
        IrisPredictionWithStringLabel prediction = predictFunction.Predict(new IrisDataWithStringLabel()
        {
            SepalLength = 5.1f,
            SepalWidth = 3.3f,
            PetalLength = 1.6f,
            PetalWidth = 0.2f,
        });

        // Outputs string : "Iris-setosa" as the prediction
        Console.WriteLine(prediction.PredictPlant);
```

Please note where the trainer is being specified in the pipeline. Also, the position and arguments specified in *MapKeyToValue*

The prediction class being used is similar to what you have in your example above:

```
    private class IrisPredictionWithStringLabel
    {
        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float[] PredictedScores { get; set; }

        public string PredictPlant { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That PredictAndMetadata was written with idea what you have Multiclass trainer in your pipeline and it will produce you "PredictedLabel" column with type of "Label" column.
I don't see trainer in your pipeline I would assume it's not present at all.

You doing this:

```
.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(("PredictedLabel", DefaultColumnNames.Label)))
```

You take "Label" of type string and convert it into "PredictedLabel" column with type Key. (Key is basically enum backed up with uint).

```
public class PurchaseDataPrediction
{
    public float[] Score;
     public string PredictedLabel;
}
```

But your result type definition has string type for PredictedLabel. While in DataView you have Key (uint).

And this is exactly what exception says:

```
Can't bind the IDataView column 'PredictedLabel' of type 'Key' to field or property 'PredictedLabel' of type 'System.String'.
```

In current moment I'm not sure what you trying to achieve with this code, if you can describe what kind of task you trying to solve, I can help you with it.

Comment: I'm following the pattern I find in examples, which adds a trainer as a separate step. I edited my question to reflect how I'm adding the trainer. Should I add it at a different point?

Answer (score 0):

I think your prediction class has `string PredictedLabel` while I believe `GetKeyValues` is expecting a key column.

For more information on key-to-value and value-to-key transformations see this sample:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/KeyToValueValueToKey.cs

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to get the predicted label. I expected the step that causes the exception to transform the key value back to a string label `mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue(("PredictedLabel", DefaultColumnNames.Label))` The samples I saw have string labels. How do I achieve that here?